# I need to find repeated values in array and make sum of them

Tags: arrays, loops, object, math, sum

I want to find duplicates in array and sum them but I can't continue after finding them.

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 8];

function count_duplicate(a) {
    let counts = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (counts[a[i]]) {
            counts[a[i]] += 1;
        } else {
            counts[a[i]] =1
        }
    }

    for (let prop in counts) {
        if (counts[prop] >= 2) {
            console.log(prop + " counted " + counts[prop] + " times.")
            // console.log(parseInt(prop) * 2);
            
            let amounts = prop * counts[prop];
        
            console.log(amounts);
        }
    }
    

    console.log(counts);
}

count_duplicate(a);
```

here the output of amounts are 4 and 6, sum of(2+2 and 3+3) but how can I make sum of them too?
expected output should be 10.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = [1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 8].reduce((acc, elem) => {
    if(elem in acc) {
        acc[elem]++;
    } else {
        acc[elem] = 1
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
let output = Object.entries(obj).filter(a => a[1] > 1).map(a => a[0] * a[1]).reduce((acc, elem) => acc+=elem, 0);
console.log(output);
```